# Is this proper use of storing values into an array via getText()?

Tags: java, arrays, gettext

In my Java program's constructor I have the following:

> ```
>   thirdRow.add(button);
>     button.setActionCommand("Sumbit");
>     button.addActionListener(this);
> ```

And here is the corresponding actionPerformed method that's supposed to take 3 values from some textfields and store them into arrays:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String arg = e.getActionCommand();

    if (arg == "Submit")
    {
    //enlarge arrays
    qtyStr = enlargeArray(qtyStr);
    typeStr = enlargeArray(typeStr);
    colorStr = enlargeArray(colorStr);

    //add from textfields into current
    qtyStr[qtyStr.length-1] = qty.getText();
    typeStr[typeStr.length-1] = type.getText();
    colorStr[colorStr.length-1] = color.getText();

    }
}

//method to enlarge an array by 1
public String[] enlargeArray(String[] currentArray)
{
    String[] newArray = new String[currentArray.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i<currentArray.length; i++)
    newArray[i] = currentArray[i];

    return newArray;
}
```

When I run the application, populate the textfields, and click the submit button nothing happens. How can I verify that my string arrays are being appended like they're supposed to?

Comment: Why aren't you using `ArrayList`? You're effectively doing similar work, but with a lot more faff (and a lot more copying).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've a problem here: `if (arg == "Submit")`

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

Also, for safety's sake, I try to use String constants wherever possible so as not to be tripped up by misspellings.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Another problem that was brought to my attention was the misspelling of the ActionCommand... I'll keep coding, thank you all!

Comment: @user3648803: that's a strong reason to use String constants.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your code this way, I would probably do two things:
1) maintain index fields for each array for the next free index, and
2) I wouldn't recommend resizing your array by 1 each time, as our current code is running through the array 2 n times (n = array length), 1st to initialize the array, and 2nd to create a new array.

Two options to optimize thisL one would be be to look into the Arrays class.  it contains methods such as [Array.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) that can perhaps be useful here.  You could also check if the array is full, and if it is then resize it by a number greater than one to reduce extra work.

For instance:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Test{
    private String[] a;
    private int next;

    public Test(int size){
        a = new String[size];
        next = 0;
    }

    public void add(String s){
        if(next == a.length){
           Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length+1);
        }
        a[next] = s;
        next++;
    }
}
```

The easiest way would be to use an ArrayList (or any class that implements the java.util.List interface), as previously mentioned by Jon Skeet - it will do all the work for you.

Comment: I've decided ArrayLists are much better for my purpose, but I don't think they can print in a Document like I need them to(with insertString at least).